# Python Pandas - Compare Columns In Separate Dataframes, Then Delete Non-Matching Rows In 1 DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to compare 2 columns in different dataframes, then delete entire non-matching rows.

The 2 columns are not of the same length.

Here is a mock-up of DataFrame #1:

[image]

Here is a mock-up of DataFrame #2:

[image]

I would like to compare the `ID_NUMBER` columns in the 2 DataFrames, then delete entire rows in DataFrame #1 if the row value cannot be found in DataFrame #2.

Currently, my code is not working:

```
DataFrame1 = np.where((DataFrame1["ID_NUMBER"] == DataFrame2["ID_NUMBER"]))
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1[df1["ID_NUMBER"].isin(df2["ID_NUMBER"])]
```