# python compare 2 dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

in reference to this post, [python-pandas-compare-columns-in-separate-dataframes-then-delete-non-matching](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/103800/python-pandas-compare-columns-in-separate-dataframes-then-delete-non-matching), I can't get the isin function to work with my 2 example dataframes :

df 1 :

```
ID_NUMBER;ITEM_TYPE;OUTCOME
AA1;AIR;GO
AA2;SEA;STOP
AA3;LAND;GO
AA4;AIR;GO
AA5;AIR;PENDING
AA6;RAIL;STOP
F15;SEA;GO
```

df2 :

```
ID_NUMBER;ITEM_TYPE
AA1;0
BC5;0
AA3;0
DJ6;0
UU6;0
JK9;0
```

**The final result that I want is when ID_NUMBER from df1_1.csv match with ID_NUMBER in df2_1.csv I must export the entire row to new results.csv file.**

My code is :

```
import pandas as pd

data_1=pd.read_csv(r"df1_1.csv")
data_2=pd.read_csv(r"df2_1.csv")
df1=pd.DataFrame(data_1)
df2=pd.DataFrame(data_2)
df_common = df1.loc[df1["ID_NUMBER"].isin(df2["ID_NUMBER"])]
```

and the result I've got :

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\Anaconda3\envs\ListingDirectory\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3621, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3620 try:
-> 3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:

File C:\Anaconda3\envs\ListingDirectory\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:136, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File C:\Anaconda3\envs\ListingDirectory\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:163, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5198, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:5206, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'ID_NUMBER'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [79], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 #df2[df2[0].isin(df1[0])]
----> 2 df1[df1["ID_NUMBER"].isin(df2["ID_NUMBER"])]

File C:\Anaconda3\envs\ListingDirectory\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:3505, in DataFrame.__getitem__(self, key)
   3503 if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3504     return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3505 indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3506 if is_integer(indexer):
   3507     indexer = [indexer]

File C:\Anaconda3\envs\ListingDirectory\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3623, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3621     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3622 except KeyError as err:
-> 3623     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3624 except TypeError:
   3625     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3626     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3627     #  the TypeError.
   3628     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 'ID_NUMBER'
```

anyone can help me please ?

Comment: The error tells you that one of the dataframes does not have a column called `ID_NUMBER`. Make sure to check the columns present in both dataframes by using the `.columns` attribute before running your code.

Comment: These pure-coding questions belong over at StackOverflow. But also @Oxbowerce seems to have nailed it.

Comment: @Oxbowerce ...that's my problem, I can see where is the error becaus both csv has the ID_NUMBER collumn (see screenshots for each file)

Comment: @iulianpn never post screenshots. Copy/paste your code and the errors you get. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

Your files are delimited by semicolons, not commas. You need to specify this in the read_csv function.

Some other problems:

- There is no need to convert a data_1 dataframe to a df1 dataframe.
- You do not need to use .loc in the selection step.

```
import pandas as pd

df1=pd.read_csv('df1_1.csv', delimiter=';')
df2=pd.read_csv('df2_1.csv', delimiter=';')
df_common = df1[df1["ID_NUMBER"].isin(df2["ID_NUMBER"])]
```

Comment: .....thx ...work like a charm

Answer (score 0):

...with real datas ....don't work :

Here is my real dataframes df1 and df2 (with columns)

```
                      0     1            2                  3
0     50027700000000002  1588  C12UA380204  79999900000000049
1     50027700000000004  2621  C14UA194954  79999900000000049
2     50027700000000062  1459  C12UA381690  79999900000000049
3     50027700000000069  1473  C14UA151593  79999900000000049
4     50027700000000156   239  H21IA197803  79999900000000049
...                 ...   ...          ...                ...
2757  50027300000000822   960  C12UA385146  79999900000000049
2758  50027300000000827   954  C12UA385147  79999900000000049
2759  50027300000000828   284  C12UA385141  79999900000000049
2760  50027300000000893  1037  C14UA150963  79999900000000049
2761  50027300000000939   636  C13UA271186  79999900000000049

[2762 rows x 4 columns]
                      0
0     50004700000000002
1     50004700000000043
2     50004700000000086
3     50004700000000124
4     50004700000000236
...                 ...
1020  50027700000002494
1021  50027700000002507
1022  50027700000002547
1023  50027700000002614
1024  50027700000002636

[1025 rows x 1 columns]
```

..and the results of :

```
df_common=df1[df1[0].isin(df2[0])]
print(df_common)
------------------------
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [0, 1, 2, 3]
Index: []
```

...whats my error ? thx for help